# JBOSS JBPM getting started

Tags: jbpm

i had expereince with oracle JPD(workflow engine), now we have decided to use open source workflow engine for our project. After googling couple of weeks we are considering to use JBOSS JBPM but i didnt get enough info related below questions as compared to my past expereince with oracle JPD.

1. In oracle JPD we were designing process in editor, creating ear and deploying it on  weblogic.The web console is provided for all process related stuff such as versioning process,triggering task,stopping task and so on. Is there any standered procedure for JBOSS JBPM. After googling for hours i found below options
   1.deploy as war with your application
   2.deploy through guvnor repository.

my concern is i want deploy it as seperate entity lets say as jar or ear external to my application.

2.How can i invoke process running on server through external programme such as simple java schedular running as standalone prgm and have it ablity to kick start process running on application server through jbpm api since most examples only explained process running in standalone JVM.

3.I want to build worklist application,where user can complete task assigned to him.

4.And finally my biggest concern is how can version my process and manage it through console ,where i can see status of processe and so on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Although there are numerous ways to load processes (from file system, classpath, etc.), the recommended way is by using the Guvnor repository to store and build your processes (they will automatically be synced with the jBPM console for execution and monitoring).
2. You can invoke various methods through the REST api of the jBPM console.
3. The same REST api can be used (and the human task list UI component that is part of the jBPM console is using the same api)
4. Managing the process definitions is done through the Guvnor repository (and associated UI).  The jBPM console can be used to start process instances, monitor them, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.As per article i setup env. using full installer and ant scripts,Below is my understand ing from articles 
a.first you need to change no of files from db folder,war files to change datase
b.There are five war files thats get deployed and  jbpm-human-task.war, jbpm-gwt-console-server.war creates tables when gets deployed

But when it comes to production already having JBOSS server, what should be stratergy to deployment. Because of  cooments length restriction i have added remaining comment below.

Comment: 1.Instead of war files creating schema , is there any script which can be run directly on database server to generate schema structure.
2.instead of madifying no of db files, running ant script and deploying war files through ant script can we create just single datasource pointing to db we created
in  step one and modifying war files according to it.
3.Can we deployed war files such as jbpm -console,GWT-console-server manually instead ant script deploy it.